# google app script about countColoredCells and sumColoredCells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the following two scripts in Google Sheets to count and sum based on background colors, and I often encounter errors: Exceeded maximum execution time (line 0).

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

and

```
function sumColoredCells(sumRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula().toString();
  formula = formula.replace(new RegExp(';','g'),',');
  
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var total = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        total=total+(values[i][j]*1);
  return total;
};
```

How can I modify them to solve this issue?
Tnanks!

Comment: Hello, can anyone help me modify the code to avoid: errors: Exceeded maximum execution time (line 0).?

Answer (score 0):

Only counts and sums cells with a number

```
function countandsum() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const bs = sh.getDataRange().getBackgrounds();
  const cob = vs.reduce((a, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (!isNaN(c)) {
        if (!a.hasOwnProperty(bs[i][j])) {
          a[bs[i][j]] = { count: 1, sum: c };
          a.pA.push(bs[i][j]);
        } else {
          a[bs[i][j]].count++;
          a[bs[i][j]].sum += c;
        }
      }
    })
    return a;
  }, { pA: [] });
  let o = cob.pA.map(p => [p,cob[p].count,cob[p].sum]);
  o.unshift(["Color","Count","Sum"])
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));
}

Execution log
9:18:36 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:18:38 PM  Info    [["Color","Count","Sum"],
["#ff0000",27,561],
["#90ee90",18,295],
["#add8e6",18,295],
["#ffc0cb",18,356],
["#ffff00",18,438],
["#a52a2a",18,434],
["#ffa500",18,331]]
9:18:39 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply.
How can I use formulas in cells to get the results of count and sum, for a specific background color number?

Comment: That's what that table is.  It's a two dimensional array that can be posted into a spreadsheet with setValues() it's got headers of Color, Count and Sum.  That's what the reduce method returned.

Comment: In my table, the calls to count and sum are separate, using the following formulas respectively. In the brackets there is first a range, then a cell with a background color to match. If it can't be called in a similar way, maybe I can't try your code.
=sumColoredCells(H6:AV6,C$1)
=countColoredCells(H6:AV6,C$1)

Comment: Doing everything in arrays is always much faster.  The reduce method return an object to the last map which has all of the unique colors and their sums and count all in one place and the map creates a two dimensional area that allows you to display it on a spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you share with me the sample google sheet file you wrote above? I will study how to modify my data file, thank you!

Comment: I don't have it any longer and the data comes from a sample data generator function and the coloring came from  something I wrote just for you answer and it's gone now.  But the code does not care how the data is organized it will take the data from any range even and active range.  You'll just have to rewrite the code a little.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but your reply is of no use to me because I don't know how to modify it based on your code to meet my needs.

Comment: - [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, or anyone who writes code because they love it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and as such I have the expectation that all users are capable of taking code and using the available documentation to figure  out how it works.  If that is no you then perhaps stack overflow is not the forum for you.  I am sorry that I could not provide you with an acceptable solution.  I will record your name and avoid answering future questions in the hope that other volunnteers will be a better fit for you.

Comment: I'm here looking to improve the usage of my code. If my reply offended you, I apologize.

Comment: I'm not offended I just cannot help provide what you ask for because I've already deleted it